# How can I view the fully qualified name for an imported class

Tags: ide, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

Is there a way I can see (in context) the fully qualified name for an imported class?

e.g. I've got this in the middle of a +200 lines php file:

`$this->helper = new ObjectManager($this);`

How can I see the full class name for `ObjectManager` (e.g. `\Framework\Helper\ObjectManager`) without scrolling to the top (where the `use` statements are), or navigating to the actual class definition (⌘+B or ⌘+Click)?

I've tried (Alt+Space) but that just displays the constructor definition. I've also tried hovering the cursor over the class and I've checked the top and bottom status bars for any hints. Couldn't find anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke `View | Quick Documentation`(<kbd>Ctrl + Q</kbd> on Windows using Default keymap) and it will tell you general class info: what interfaces it implements, class description (from PHPDoc if present), what namespace it is etc.

An example for one of the classes from Laravel 5.4 framework:

[image]

---

You can also try invoking code completion popup (<kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> here) with caret placed somewhere close to the end of the class name (so it precisely matches the class) -- it will show what namespace it's from:

[image]